# iso 8601 conversion Week in URL 2014-W43

Tags: asp.net, url, asp.net-web-api, iso8601, nodatime

I am writing an ASP.Net Web Api (2.2). It is for a report system (pretty charts and things)

I want to offer Day/Week/Month Views of the data with prev/next buttons.

My URI path looks like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "Api UriPathExtension Report DateCategory ISO 8601",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{dateCategory}/{iso8601date}.{ext}",
    defaults: new
    {
        ext = RouteParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

I want to take my iso8601date and process it depending on which value (Day/Week/Month) are in the dateCategory parameter.

```
/// <param name="dateCategory">string {Day/Week/Month}</param>
/// <param name="iso8601date">The iso8601 compliant 
/// date(2014-10-22),
/// week(2014-W43),
/// or month(2014-10)</param>

DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(iso8601date,null,DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);

// 2014-10-22 works fine: 2014-10-22T00:00
// 2014-10 works fine: 2014-10-01T00:00
// 2014-W43 throws error: 

An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 5.
```

Is there any way to parse this 2014-W43 into a time I can use in JSON.net serialization. Maybe with NodaTime? I can't seem to find anything.

I could build it, but it seems like there should be a solution for this. It is [part of the iso8601 spec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) according to Wikipedia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though it is part of ISO-8601, there is nothing built-in to .NET or to Noda Time to parse a value like `"2014-W43"`, and there is a very good reason why:

That value represents an *entire* week.  The resulting data from parsing it would have to be a *range* of values.   In Noda Time, there is the `Interval` type to represent a range of `Instant` values, but there are no other general purpose range types.

To be more specific, a full week should be modeled as a fully-inclusive range of time zone ignorant date-only values.  Using Noda Time, you would have a pair of `LocalDate` values.

Without Noda Time, you'll run into the issue that .NET doesn't have a date-only data type.  If you use a pair of `DateTime` values with the time at midnight, then you'll need to adjust the end date one day forward, and use half-open interval logic such that the start date is inclusive but the end date is exclusive.

The parsing itself is fairly trivial, but you won't be able to use any of the existing parsers.  Here, this should get you started.  I'm sure you can complete any remaining functionality you might need:

```
public struct LocalDateRange
{
    public LocalDate StartDate { get; private set; }
    public LocalDate EndDate { get; private set; }

    public int LengthInDays
    {
        get
        {
            var period = Period.Between(StartDate, EndDate, PeriodUnits.Days);
            return (int) period.Days + 1;
        }
    }

    public LocalDateRange(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate)
        : this()
    {
        StartDate = startDate;
        EndDate = endDate;
    }

    public static LocalDateRange ParseFromIsoWeek(string s)
    {
        var m = Regex.Match(s, @"(\d{4})-W(\d{1,2})");
        if (!m.Success)
            throw new FormatException();

        var year = int.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value);
        var weekNumber = int.Parse(m.Groups[2].Value);

        // Note: ISO8601 weeks run from Monday through Sunday, per spec
        var startDate = LocalDate.FromWeekYearWeekAndDay(
            year, weekNumber, IsoDayOfWeek.Monday);
        var endDate = LocalDate.FromWeekYearWeekAndDay(
            year, weekNumber, IsoDayOfWeek.Sunday);

        return new LocalDateRange(startDate, endDate);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("[{0} - {1}]", StartDate, EndDate);
    }
}
```

Calling it is simple, like this:

```
var week = LocalDateRange.ParseFromIsoWeek("2014-W43");
```

Note, I didn't implement equality or comparison functionality in this example.

Comment: Awesome. I may end up using the actual start date for simplicity but this feels so much more correct.